# Error al declarar un campo usuario en una tabla única

Tags: sql

He creado una sencilla tabla con SQL con el siguiente código:

```
CREATE TABLE USUARIOS_PASS (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
USUARIOS VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL, PASSWORD VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL)
```

Luego he ido a crear un usuario para poder comprobar que iba bien pero me da error (lo pongo a continuación).

```
INSERT INTO USUARIOS_PASS (ID, USUARIOS, PASSWORD) VALUES (1, “Carlos”, “1234”)
```

**Error**: 
*#1054 - La columna 'Carlos' en field list es desconocida*

He visto que si pongo,

```
INSERT INTO USUARIOS_PASS (ID, USUARIOS, PASSWORD) VALUES (1, “1234”, “Carlos”)
```

Si que me deja, pero obviamente me pone 1234 como nombre de usuario y Carlos como contraseña y no es lo que yo quería.

Debe ser absurdo pero no veo el error.

Salud!

Comment: Lo que dice @AlfredoPaz en su respuesta es totalmente cierto, sin embargo esa no es la fuente del error, el cual ocurre porque usas este tipo de comillas en el dato a insertar `“`. En MySQL ese tipo de comillas funciona como un *identificador*, pues se usa para identificar nombres de tablas, de columnas, etc. De hecho, lo que ocurre es que el manejador interpreta **que estás identificando una columna llamada `Carlos`**, la cual no existe. Para los `VARCHAR` debes usar la comilla simple: **`INSERT INTO USUARIOS_PASS (USUARIOS, PASSWORD) VALUES ('Carlos', '1234')`**

Comment: excelente y necesaria observacion @A.Cedano

Comment: @AlfredoPaz si quieres puedes editar tu respuesta agregándolo, porque ese es el motivo real del error. Saludos.

Comment: hecho @A.Cedano saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te saludo y te comento lo siguiente:

Cuando declaras un campo en una tabla como PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, no es necesario meterlo dentro de la instrucción SQL pues el gestor lee que el primer valor que espera la tabla posee esas características y lo insertará en automático; luego entonces todo tu SQL debería quedar así

> Con el apoyo de A.Cedano también te comento que dentro de tu
>   instrucción SQL, el uso de las comillas **“** es para hacer
>   identificación de nombres de tablas, columnas, etc; entonces en tus
>   campos de tipo **VARCHAR** debes utilizar las comillas simples para
>   que el interprete de MySQL lea el valor Carlos como una cadena de
>   texto y no como el nombre de una columna

**Declaración de la tabla**

```
CREATE TABLE USUARIOS_PASS
(ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
USUARIOS VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
PASSWORD VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL);
```

**Inserción de los datos**

```
INSERT INTO USUARIOS_PASS (USUARIOS, PASSWORD) VALUES ('Carlos', '1234');
```